# Closing PySide2 application kills QProcess - not true with PyQt4

Tags: subprocess, pyqt4, pyside2, qprocess

I have a simple test PyQt4 application where i'm using a QProcess to start a program (linux) and print the stdout. When I close the PyQt4 application the child process (started by QProcess) keeps running, which is what I want.
However when I run the same example using PySide2 instead (switching QtGui to QtWidgets etc) and I then close the PySide2 application, the child process also closes..

Is this a bug with either PyQt4 or PySide2? And is there a way to get PySide2 to have the same behaviour as PyQt4 in this case? I know there is startDetached on the QProcess but then I lose access to stdout so this isn't an option for me..

EDIT, added simple PySide2 example. In this case i'm opening Dolphin as the program - this isn't the program i'm opening in my real world application but it mimics the same behaviour

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtWidgets,QtCore, QtWidgets

class gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(gui, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def stdoutReady(self, process):
        data = str(self.process.readAllStandardOutput())

        print('STDOUT: {}'.format(data))

    def stderrorReady(self, process):
        data = str(self.process.readAllStandardError())

        print('STDERROR: {}'.format(data))

    def processFinished(self, exitCode, exitStatus):
        print('EXIT CODE: {}, EXIT STATUS: {}'.format(exitCode, exitStatus))

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)

        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(lambda: self.stdoutReady(self.process))
        self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(lambda: self.stderrorReady(self.process))

        self.process.start('dolphin')

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui=gui()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc, I added an example

Comment: I think it is a pyqt bug because as seen in the QProcess [source code](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.14.0/src/corelib/io/qprocess.cpp#L1259) it kills the process when QProcess is destroyed, I think PyQt5 does not invoke the QProcess destroyer. And PySide2 has no errors in this case.